# Why my table description throws an error in mysql?

Tags: mysql

---

I want to view the description of my table.But i found the following errors?

```
mysql> describe users;
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_1578_0.MYI' (Errcode: 30)
```

Comment: Looks like a problem on your hard disk. No space or permissions issue, or your file is corrupted

Comment: yeah looks scary .

Comment: What operating system?  What are the permissions on /tmp?